# solving simple system in a linear differential quasi-polynomal equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

$$x''+x=4te^t$$
We find the fundamental system is $$\{\cos t,\sin t\}$$
after that
$$
f(t)=P_m(t)e^{λt}
$$
$$
m=1;\;
l=1;\;
s=0;\;
Q_m(t)=at+b$$
So we have to find the partial solution $$z(x)=x^sQ_m(t)e^{λt}=(at+b)e^t$$ 
$$z''=(at+b)e^t+2ae^t$$
We replace in the equation and we have: 
$$(at+b)e^t+2ae^t+(at+b)e^t=4te^t \iff at+b+a-2t=0$$
Final answer is $$y=c_1\cos t+c_2\sin t+(at+b)e^t.$$
My question is how do we find $a$ and $b$, are there any mistakes in my calculations?

Comment: you must plugg your solution into the differential equation, the solution is given by $$x \left( t \right) =\sin \left( t \right) {\it \_C2}+\cos \left( t
 \right) {\it \_C1}+2\, \left( t-1 \right) {{\rm e}^{t}}
$$

Comment: I don't understand how do you find that $$z=2(t−1)e^t$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got as the last equation
$$
at+b+a-2t=0.
$$
Now you just compare coefficients to get the linear system
$$
a-2=0\\
b+a=0
$$
which is now trivial to solve